# how can I print from the java class one bye one

Tags: java

> in the main

```
else if(user ==3) {
            
            
            todolists.Displayitem();
            duedatelists.Displayitem();
            prilists.Displayitem();
            System.out.println("");
            
            
            
        }
```

> in the class Todo

```
public void Displayitem() {
        if(todolist.size()==0) {
            System.out.println("All Done !!!");
        }else {
        System.out.println("To Do List");
        int index =1;
        for(String item: todolist) {
            System.out.print("(" +index++ +")"+item+ " ");
        }
        
        }
    }
```

> I think it would print something like (1) test 1 DATE mmddyy LEVEL (2)
> test 2 DATE mmddyy LEVEL
>
> but it prints (1) test1 (2) test2 DATE DATE LEVEL LEVEL

Comment: First you print all the todo strings, then you print all the dates, then you print all the priorities. Why do you not expect them to print the way they have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following lines from main and put them in DisplayItem

```
        duedatelists.Displayitem();
        prilists.Displayitem();
        System.out.println("");
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't print anything, maybe the .Displayitem comes from different class ?? I actually have 4 class in the package MAIN TODO DUEDATE PRIORITY

Comment: You need to post more code

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have three lists to print:

```
todolists.Displayitem();
duedatelists.Displayitem();
prilists.Displayitem();
```

However you want information from all three lists printed together. So how about assuming that you have an equal number of entries in all three lists, then you can do

```
for (int i=0;i<todolists.size()) {
   System.out.print(i);
   System.out.print(todolists.get[i]);
   System.out.print(duedatelists.get[i]);
   System.out.print(prilists.get[i]);
}
```

You will have to add whitespace/formatting to your taste to make it readable though.